# Problema React Navigator 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Actualice la version de react navigator, especificamente de la vercion `"react-navigation": "^3.11.1"`, a la versión `"@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.7"`, ahora al querer utilizar:

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
if (props.navigation && props.isLogged) {
  props.navigation.navigate('Main');
}
return null; }
```

Se que el `props.navigation.navigate();` es de la versión antigua... que función, ¿puedo utilizar que remplace `props.navigation.navigate();`, pero que haga la misma funcionalidad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema siempre fue que nunca se heredaba la propiedad navigation. Al no seer una función, nunca pude heredarle las propiedades de navigation, así que lo solucione incluyendo la pantalla en en el *<Stack.Navigator>* así:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Loading">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Loading"
          component={AuthLoading}
          options={{ headerShown: false, gesturesEnabled: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoadingView}
          options={{ headerShown: false, gesturesEnabled: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Navigation"
          component={NewsStack}
          options={{ headerShown: false, gesturesEnabled: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```